# How to draw sprites on an arc pattern in GMS2?

Tags: game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

I've been trying to get this concept UI design working in the game:

[Concept UI Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4XiR.png)

I got the health display just fine. Then I tried to add the orbs in and here's how far I've got it so far:

[What I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa1uc.png)

The orbs are getting drawn in the correct place but in the wrong order. The **first one getting drawn is the dark red orb** and **white is the last**. I need it to start drawing the first orb (dark red) at the bottom of the health display and then making its way counter-clockwise.

Here's the code:

```
//Mana UI
for (var i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    draw_sprite(spr_mana_orb, 0, _centerx+28*cos(i*(0.15*pi)), _centery+28*sin(i*(0.15*pi)));
}
```

As you can guess, I'm lacking math skills.

Comment: I'm surprised you've already gotten so far, you might need to just reverse one or two values to get the desired result. Perhaps a form of drawing tool or a seperate empty game environment could help if the compile times takes too long.

Comment: @Steven You were right. I only had to use sin incrementation on x and cos on y, swapping the functions around. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to hear it worked out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sin for x incrementation and cos for y swaps the axis of the drawing circle, resulting in the style I wanted.

Like this:

```
//Mana UI
for (var i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    draw_sprite(spr_mana_orb, 0, _centerx+28*sin(i*(0.15*pi)), _centery+28*cos(i*(0.15*pi)));
}
```